# Var visible in the ViewDIdLoad but not somewhere else

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables, instance-variables, protected

I'm programming one iphone app, and there is a problem; I can use a NSDate variable in the viewDidLoad method but not somewhere else! How can it be made? how can it be resolved?

here's my important lines:

```
@interface GraphNavController : UINavigationController {

IBOutlet UIImage *image;
CGPoint gestureStartPoint;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
NSCalendar *gregorian;

@public
NSDate *date;
```

}

And in the implementation code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

//  Set the GMT @ 2
gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+2"]];

dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setMonth:11];

[dateComponents setMonth:11];// tests ^^
date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"-->  Date : %@ - DComponents's : %d-%d-%d - gregorian : %@",date, [dateComponents day], [dateComponents month], [dateComponents year], [gregorian calendarIdentifier]); // is running here completely well
```

}

And the date variable is hidden in any other method of this class...

I already try to put that variable in @public, @private, @package, ... but nothing is running.

The app is killing without give any description of the problem! I just have to put a Log of the date anywhere else than in the viewOnLoad and the crash appears...

Comment: Are you trying to add 11 months to the current date?

Answer (score 1):

`dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` returns an autoreleased object. You should retain it. If you use a property:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSDate *date;
```

then you can do this:

```
self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Comment: Better yet, make it `@property(retain,nonatomic) NSDate *date;`

Comment: @Martin : I made that modification but the app still crash :-/

Comment: @clement If you use a property, make sure you use `self.date` instead of `date` (see edited answer)

Comment: @albertamg : Thanks for your help, really... but I've difficulties to implement it, first error in : self.date = [[NSDate alloc] init]; (reason: '-[GraphNavController setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...). If I comment this line, I have an error in this line : self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

Comment: @clement don't forget @synthesize date; for your property

Comment: @clement also, you don't need to do `date = [[NSDate alloc] init];`, just `self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];`